# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet when loading wsgi.py

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, python-venv

I have a problem with Django and wsgi that I cannot pinpoint. The app works fine on my local test server and it also works fine on a local apache WAMP setup (without any venvs). When deploying it to our Linux server again the local test server runs (as does makemigrations, migrate or check):

```
python3 manage.py runserver
/home/www-test/myapp-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.8) or chardet (2.0.3) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
/home/www-test/myapp-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.8) or chardet (2.0.3) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 18, 2020 - 16:22:20
Django version 2.2.11, using settings 'myapp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.



 python3 manage.py check
 /home/www-test/myapp-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: 
 RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.8) or chardet (2.0.3) doesn't match a supported version!
 RequestsDependencyWarning)
 System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

However when I try to deploy it with wsgi/Apache on the Linux machine I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myapp/wsgi.py", line 20, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/www-test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/www-test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/www-test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/www-test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/www-test/myapp/myapp/maintenance.py", line 9, in <module>
    from imageplus.models import ImagePlus
  File "/home/www-test/myapp/imageplus/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from userprofile.models import Userprofile
  File "/home/www-test/myapp/userprofile/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/home/www-test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/www-test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/www-test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 103, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/www-test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/www-test/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I suspect it has something to do with venv or with missing paths, but I don't know where to start. wsgi.py looks like this:

```
"""
WSGI config for myapp project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os, sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')
sys.path.append('/home/www-test/myapp/myapp')
sys.path.append('/home/www-test/myapp')
sys.path.append('/home/www-test/myapp-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages')


application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any suggestions a to where to even start with hunting this error would be very much appreciated.

[edit:]

I traced the error further to apps.py of myapp which looks like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from threading import Thread 
from django.utils import timezone
import time
import schedule
import os
from decouple import config

class SebastianConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN', None) == 'true':
            return

        import myapp.signals

        if config('AUTOMAINTENANCE', cast=bool)==False:
            print ('[myApp]: auto maintenance is disabled')
            return

        from myapp.maintenance import maintenance

        def scheduler_demon():
            while True:
                schedule.run_pending()
                time.sleep(60)  

        def aliveping():
            print(f'[myApp]:ping {timezone.now()}')

        schedule.every(5).minutes.do(aliveping)
        schedule.every(24).hours.do(maintenance)
        schedule.run_all()

        worker=Thread(target=scheduler_demon,args=(),)
        worker.daemon=True
        worker.start()
```

In theory this should not cause problems as fas as my understanding of Django goes. Its also the ONLY spot maintenance is imported.

Now the funny thing is I removed that passage and wsgi worked like a charm. I added the passage once again and **SURPRISE** it still works like a charm?!!?

Comment: Mostly unrelated, but you should only add your django project's root directory (and of course your venv site-packages) to your `sys.path`, else you will probably get bitten by the (very nasty) [double import gotcha](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap).

Comment: wrt/ your issue: it looks that you're trying to import myapp/myapp/maintenance.py - which itself imports other models - before all models have been loaded by Django. Impossible to tell exactly which module imports this one, but it should be easy to find out.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I meanwhile traced the bug further (see edit) and kinda solved it. I just don't get why?

Comment: Did you restart your server after adding  the import back ? I wouldn't rely on this working reliably.

Comment: Yes, lots of times. And as I said my WAMP testserver runs with this config for about 6 months now and never manifested the problem.So yes I am nervous as well that this could break again and will rework the code either way. Its just hard to say if it is fixed when you do not understand the error and cannot reproduce it anymore

Comment: Well, yes indeed :-/ A couple things though first, by all means, fix your wsgi file to only add the correct dir to your sys.path (this might needed fixing a couple imports), and (depending on how you deploy to production) make sure you clean up all stale .pyc files. Both (double import and stale .pyc files) can lead to really weird bugs.